# Does a return statement in the try block wait for an await statement in the finally block?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Consider the following snippet:

```
try {
    const client = getClientThatMustBeClosed();
    const data = await shortRunningOperation(client);
    return Promise.resolve(data);
} catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
} finally {
    // any exception in the following function is caught and dealt with internally...
    await longRunningOperation(client);
    client.close();
}
```

Ideally I want to return data to the calling function right after `shortRunningOperation()` completes, without waiting for `longRunningOperation()` to complete.  But closing the `client` must wait until after `longRunningOperation()` completes.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gctwjL5r/) would suggest that the return statement waits for the finally block to complete... in which case, what is the correct way to get data back to the calling function ASAP without waiting for `longRunningOperation()` to complete?

Comment: `return Promise.resolve(data)` is overkill. Simply `return data` and `return error`. But as soon as you use `return`, the function execution ends. I don't think `await longRunningOperation` ever happens.

Comment: Seems like it would be easy enough to try and see. Set up some `async` functions with `setTimeout` and `console.log`s and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some simple test code that shows that the `finally` block does execute, even after the `try` block returns.

```js
function wait (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  })
}

async function test () {
  try {
    await wait(1000);
    console.log('try block complete');
    return;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('catch err:', err);
    return;
  } finally {
    await wait(3000);
    console.log('finally block complete');
  }
}

test();
```

But as the OP notes, the try block value will not be returned until the finally block is completed.

If the try return value is wanted immediately, don't use a finally block. Instead, put the long duration cleanup code in the try block, but don't use the `await`.

```js
function wait (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  })
}

async function test () {
  try {
    await wait(1000);
    console.log('try complete');
    
    // put cleanup here without using await
    wait(3000).then(() => {
      console.log('cleanup complete');
    });
    
    return 'try return';
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('catch err:', err);
    return err;
  }
}

test().then(result => console.log('result:', result));
```

**Update:** You can use a `finally` block without blocking (delaying) the `try` return, but only if the `finally` block does not contain a `return` or `await`.

```js
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function test() {
  try {
    await wait(1000);
    console.log('try complete');
    return 'try return';
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('catch err:', err);
    return err;
  } finally {
    // cleanup without await
    wait(3000).then(() => {
      console.log('long duration cleanup complete');
    });
    // do not return here
  }
}

test().then((result) => console.log('result:', result));
```

Comment: The try block completes, but does the function actually only return a value (in your case `undefined`) after the finally block completes?  I edited my question to include a jsfiddle which illustrates this nuance better.  In my case I want to get a return value back ASAP.

Comment: Here is your snippet modified to include a return value: https://jsfiddle.net/q841k9x0/

Comment: @drmrbrewer See the second code snippet, which returns the try result as soon as it's available, and performs the long duration cleanup.

Comment: cunning... a combination of 'old' `.then().catch()` and 'new' `async/await`!  Here is a slightly modified version (mainly for my own benefit) which attempts to make this mock-up closer to what I'm aiming for in practice: https://jsfiddle.net/gb7oqvc0/ ... Thanks!